# laravel vue.js axios json object extra string appended

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I started working with laravel and vuejs. I have encountered a problem fter doing a post to the server and returning a message. The result contains an extra string to the json object returned by the server. My server side code

```
try{
    $this->_gFormsService->saveGlobalForm($request);
}catch (\Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}


return ['message'=>'Form created'];
```

Client side code

```
submit(requestType, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            delete this.errors;
            axios[requestType](url, this)
                .then(response => {

                    debugger
                    this.onSuccess(response.data);

                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {

                    debugger
                    this.onFail(error.response.data);

                    reject(error.response.data);
                });
        });
    }
```

The resulted json response is

```
{data: "section{"message":"Form created"}"
```

As you can see it appends "section" to the jsonobject and i have no idea why.

Thx

Comment: This is certainly not normal.  Are you working with a stock Laravel install?  Have you added any filters to your routes anywhere?

Comment: No filters. This is why everything is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a  bona fide JSON response from Laravel:

```
return response()->json(['message'=>'Form created']);
```

Then on your front-end you'll be able to get your message property from response.data .

Comment: I tried. The result is the same. I think the problem may be on the client side. The result is : "section{"message":"Form created"}" . I am using mixins in vuejs, and i am using them globally. I have a property section in that mixins file. Maybe axios gets conflicted when preparing the response data?